# Issues during Installation of windows service

Tags: c#

I am installing windows service using installutil.exe and got the following error.

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>InstallUtil.exe D:\WindowsService1
.exe;

> Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Installation utility Version
>   4.0.30319.33440 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved. Exception occurred while initializing the installation:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///D:\Win dowsService1.exe;' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file s pecified..

My file is located in exactly that location.

Comment: It says "**or one of its dependencies**". Are you sure all assemblies needed to run your service are copied next to it or registered in GAC?

Comment: maybe you mistyped the path or name. or you are missing DLL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install your service with `sc` command.
open an `CMD` with admin permission and run following command to install.

```
SC create WindowsService1 displayname= "WindowsService1" binpath= "D:\WindowsService1.exe" start= auto
```

Answer (score 0):

Fist thing I see is the space before ".exe" but that is probably a type here on the site. What you could do is build the service with all reference set  "copy local" to true, and copy the entire bin folder to the machine you need to publisch